# How to add entity to the databse without adding related entitiy in DB as well?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I have a problem adding one entity using JPA save without error :

`JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column`

because i add empty entity to the object i want to save. 
how can i save one entity and tell it's related one to ignore this transaction?

For example i have student and  i have student_info OneToOne Relationship. I want to save student and not assign information to him yet, but my student_info tells me : hey student_info column 1 can not be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't!

If there is a constraint on the database like Not Null, primary or foreign key then you can only save the data to this table when the constraints are fulfilled.